# How to pause figures in beamer

Tags: beamer, graphics, pause

I would to `\pause` two different images (as I can to do with text). This is the *ideal* code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{Copenhagen}
\setbeamercovered{dynamic}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\centering
\includegraphics{gfx/img1} \\
\pause
\includegraphics{gfx/img2}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

What is the *real* code?

I see both the images on each pause.

Edit: I would to preserve the absolute position of the images and the `dynamic` behaviour.

Comment: Your code *is* the real code (adding `\par` or a blank line after the second \includegraphics).

Comment: @GonzaloMedina It doesn't work =(

Comment: Saying just "it doesn't work" is useless. What exactly doesn't work? What error(s) do you get? I did a test before posting my comment and it worked, so please explain what exactly doesn't work.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina It compiles but I see both the images. I now also add something in the preamble. Maybe the `dynamic` option is the problem?

Comment: Yes, `dynamic` was the key here!

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You can also use

```
\visible<1>{content}
```

in order to have content only visible on slide 1, but reserve space for it on the other slides. This may help you with your positioning problem.

Comment: I added to my answer a complete example using your suggestion; I hope it's OK with you.

Comment: Thank you. Is it possible to preserve the `dynamic` behaviour? i.e. not visible image semitransparent.

Comment: @Baduel I don't think it is possible with `\includegraphics`, as beamer does not know how to make the image semitransparent. That is in fact why you saw both images in your first version. You can try drawing a tikz picture instead of using `\includegraphics`, and it should show semitransparent even in your first code version.

Comment: Ok thanks. I don't know tikz, but I will remedy.

Answer (score 26):

You can use `\only`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\setbeamercovered{dynamic}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\centering
\only<1->{\includegraphics[width=4cm]{ctanlion}}
\only<2>{\includegraphics[width=4cm]{ctanlion}}\par
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

To preserve the relative position in slide one, you can use `overlayarea`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\setbeamercovered{dynamic}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\vskip10pt
\begin{overlayarea}{\textwidth}{.45\textheight}
  \centering
  \only<1-|handout:0>{\includegraphics[width=4cm]{ctanlion1}}
\end{overlayarea}%
\begin{overlayarea}{\textwidth}{.45\textheight}
  \centering
  \only<2>{\includegraphics[width=4cm]{ctanlion2}}
\end{overlayarea}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

and, since `\includegraphics` is overlay-aware, you can also say

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\setbeamercovered{dynamic}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\vskip10pt
\begin{overlayarea}{\textwidth}{.45\textheight}
  \centering
  \includegraphics<1-|handout:0>[width=4cm]{ctanlion}
\end{overlayarea}%
\begin{overlayarea}{\textwidth}{.45\textheight}
  \centering
  \includegraphics<2>[width=4cm]{ctanlion}
\end{overlayarea}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

or, even simpler, `\visible`, as suggested by **silvado**; here's a complete version of the code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\setbeamercovered{dynamic}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \centering
  \visible<1-|handout:0>{\includegraphics[width=4cm]{ctanlion1}\\}
  \visible<2>{\includegraphics[width=4cm]{ctanlion2}}\par
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Perfect, is possible to preserve the original position? I wouldn't that first image disappears.

Comment: @Baduel: see my updated answer.

Comment: Just make only the second one `only`. Also note that you can use ranges, e.g. `only<2->` for one image and `only<3->` fo the next. Then in the first subslide no image would be seen, in the second only the first, and in the third (and all following, if any follow) both.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Very nearly to what I want. Is it possible to preserve the absolute position in each step?

Comment: Also note that  want to do this in order to print the frame in only one slide, when I will put the `handouts` option.

Comment: @Baduel: With handouts, you have to extend the specification in \only. For example: `\only<1-|handout:0>{incomplete pic}\only<2>{complete pic}`.

Comment: @Baduel: see again my updated answer ;-)

Comment: Doesnt \includegraphics<1>[]{} work? I think it used to...

Comment: @MartinH: yes that would work but won't preserve by itself the position of the first image in both slides; used together with `overlayarea`, however, it produces the desired result; I've added the code to my answer.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Thank you for your patience. Your code works fine in the example. Unfortunately this is no good yet if add some text in the frame (second image gets out from the slide). Since the `\visible` solution is simpler and works fine also with some added text, I accept the silvado answer. However I upvote your answer for the use of `\only` (very useful). Thanks.

Comment: What a big effort! Think I'll just create a new slide... Why there is any point to `includegrahics<1>{...}` given that it doesn't preserve position is beyond me.

Answer (score 6):

I have just answered a very similar question [here on tex.stackexchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/136171/29028), and I figured it would be a good solution for your problem too.

So, in short, your code is almost perfect if you download this [custom style file](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/gdevenyi/phd_thesis/master/presentation/fixpauseincludegraphics.sty) and add it with a `usepackage` statement:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

%% %% %% ADD THIS LINE
\usepackage{fixpauseincludegraphics}

\usetheme{Copenhagen}
\setbeamercovered{dynamic}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\centering
\includegraphics{gfx/img1} \\
\pause
\includegraphics{gfx/img2}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

(the style file contains a rewritten version of `\includegraphics` that will draw your image with some added opacity).

Comment: I just tried this and I get "! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \transparent@value 
                              /100
"

Comment: @Jealie, the second link is not working as expected.

Comment: Check [this](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/gdevenyi/phd_thesis/master/presentation/fixpauseincludegraphics.sty) for the package

Comment: @ArturoVolpe: thank you for the new link! I have updated the response.

Comment: @felix apparenlty, you need a `\begin{itemize}[<+->]` somewhere before the \includegraphics.