# Beamer pause and grey not in order

Tags: beamer, graphics, pause

I have a slide that is produced by the following codes:

```
\begin{frame}[plain]
\begin{itemize}
\item Current work 0
\item Future works 1
\item Future works 2
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[scale=0.35]{xxx.pdf}
\end{center}
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
```

Now I want to display the first item "Current work 0" and the graphics `xxx.pdf` at the same time, while grey out the two "Future works". Then on the next slide I want to display the two "Future works" items and grey out "Current works" and the graphics. Is there any way to achieve that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following MWE provides `\hidecontent[<transparency>]{<stuff>}` that hides `<stuff>` with a white transparent box. Optional transparency is set as `<transparency>` (provided by Heiko's [`transparent` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/transparent)); default is `0.25` or 25%:

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}% http://ctan.org/pkg/beamer
\usepackage{transparent}% http://ctan.org/pkg/transparent
\setbeamercovered{transparent}
\newcommand{\hidecontent}[2][0.25]{{% \hidecontent[<transparency>]{<stuff>}
  \setbox9=\hbox{#2}% Store <stuff> in \box9 to obtain height/width
  \transparent{#1}\ooalign{\usebox9\cr\color{white}\rule{\wd9}{\ht9}\cr}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[plain]
  \begin{itemize}
    \item<1> Current work 0
    \item<2> Future works 1
    \item<2> Future works 2
    \begin{center}
      \mbox{\only<1>{\includegraphics[scale=0.35]{example-image-a.pdf}}}%
      \mbox{\only<2>{\hidecontent{\includegraphics[scale=0.35]{example-image-a.pdf}}}}%
    \end{center}
  \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[`beamer`](http://ctan.org/pkg/beamer) doesn't adequately handle hiding of graphics, hence the use of `\hidecontent`. This works well with rectangular content. Other content (textual, for example), is best dealt with by `beamer` itself.

Comment: This solution is very good, but does not work well (knowable "line" in the picture + some hight problems after a linebreak) with pictures in a raisebox (took me some time to note that).

Answer (score 7):

I can suggest a less complicated way than what Werner proposed. It consists in one include and no change to your code, but you have to download a custom style that remedy to your problem.

1. Download [`fixpauseincludegraphics.sty`](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/gdevenyi/phd_thesis/master/presentation/fixpauseincludegraphics.sty) and place it into the same folder as your `.tex` file.
2. Include the package with `\usepackage{fixpauseincludegraphics}`.
3. (optional) Check out [this post](https://web.archive.org/web/20140511130153/http://funkysea.com/?p=6) to understand how it works - long story short, this solution consists in an overloading of `\includegraphics` to redraw the pictures using `tikz` to change the opacity according to the `beamer` transparency state.

Comment: `fixpauseincludegraphics.sty` link is broken.

Comment: When extra space around images introduced by `fixpauseincludegraphics` is a problem and the original `\includegraphics`’s positioning is needed (like in [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/136391)), the solution is to change `\node[opacity=\transparent@value/100]` to `\node[opacity=\transparent@value/100, style={inner sep=0, outer sep=0}]` within the STY file.