# TikZ: remove margin, padding, border around nodes containing images

Tags: tikz-pgf, spacing, graphics, margins, arrows

I want to create a simple figure where images are connected with arrows.
Here is what I did:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[](A) {\includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth]{a}};
\node[right=1mm of A](B) {\includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth]{b}};
\draw[->] (A) to (B);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image: example]

But I want the arrow to start and end right at the images with no space between. How can I do that?

Comment: add `every node/.style={inner sep=0,outer sep=0}` to the picture options

Comment: @percusse Would you like to write an answer, or is there a duplicate somewhere?

Comment: @percusse / tauran: Would either of you like to write an answer? I thought I remembered a duplicate for this one but can't find it...

Comment: And ``every node/.style={inner xsep=0pt,outer xsep=0pt}`` for no sep. See Claudio Fiandrino: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/95649/reduce-white-space-around-tikz-picture

Answer (score 52, accepted):

The extra space is added according to the `inner sep` and `outer sep` amounts. If you zero them out the image is tightly packed inside the node thanks to `inner sep=0` and moreover the arrows start right from the border thanks to `outer sep=0`

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{mwe} % For dummy images 
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={inner sep=0,outer sep=0}]
\node[](A) {\includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth]{example-image-a}};
\node[right=1cm of A](B) {\includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth]{example-image-b}};
\draw[->] (A) to (B);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]