# Beamer Presentation: Stepwise Uncover Images

Tags: beamer, graphics, lyx

I don't even know if this is possible, but here goes:

I'm writing slides for an upcoming presentation using the default LyX Beamer template. I am also using the `uncover everything in a stepwise fashion` option:

```
\beamerdefaultoverlayspecification{<+->}
```

However, when one of the bullets that I want to uncover in this stepwise fashion contains an image, the image is not "dimmed out" when it should be (as can be seen in the attached screenshot - those graphs are supposed to be dimmed in the first slide).

[image]

How can I apply the stepwise uncover feature to images as well?

An MWE can be downloaded [here](http://www.filehosting.org/file/details/429900/MWE.lyx)

Comment: Hmm... I did a simple test and everything worked as expected; could you please add to your question a minimal example document illustrating the problem?

Comment: I'd be surprised if the dimming of "invisible" material works for images as well as text.  You might have to handcode it.

Comment: Just added the MWE to the question (as a download)

Comment: @inspectorG4dget that is a file generated for LyX which contains a lot of non LaTeX code, so I cannot follow the example. Could you provide a proper `.tex` file?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It seems that beamer does not know how to dim pictures. I solved this problem by adding following TeX code around the picture:

`\only<2>{` ...the picture... `}`

That will show "...the picture..." only in step 2. Hence, you might need to adjust the number 2 to your needs. It is also possible to use ranges `\only<3-5>` etc.

**EDIT:** Note that by using `\only` the space will change if no `\only<1>` is provided. Using `\visible` might be better.

See also related question for LaTeX: [How to pause figures in beamer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/37490/how-to-pause-figures-in-beamer).