# Set a transparent icon in beamer's bibliography

Tags: beamer, bibliographies

I want to `\uncover` a citation in a particular overlay. The problem is that the bibliography's item icon (article in this case) is not set as transparent, but the text is.

How can I make the icon transparent also?

Here is the MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\setbeamercovered{transparent}

\begin{thebibliography}{1}
\uncover<1>{
    \setbeamertemplate{bibliography item}[article]
    \bibitem{}
    \scriptsize Doe, J. (1975).
    \newblock\scriptsize Title of the first paper.
    \newblock {\em Journal.}
}
\uncover<1-2>{
    \setbeamertemplate{bibliography item}[article]
    \bibitem{}
    \scriptsize Doe, J. (1980).
    \newblock\scriptsize Title of the second paper.
    \newblock {\em Journal.}
}
\end{thebibliography}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

And here is the output:

[image: output gif]

Comment: I don't think it's possible, but I hope to be proved wrong.

Comment: This is the case in general when you include an *image*. If the graphic was drawn in TeX, then the overlay specification works as expected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT:** There are two possibilities for obtaining the desired transparency effect. The original solution making use only of the `beamer` code is given in Method 2. A *simpler and maybe more elegant solution* based on the `transparent` package is given as Method 1.

### Method 1

Using the package `transparent` it is possible to create a simple transparent environment that makes text and icons transparent on the desired overlay.

The output:

[image: Output Method 1]

The code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

% Required package
\usepackage{transparent}

% Create transparent environment
\newenvironment<>{transpenv}{\bgroup\only#1{\transparent{0.2}}}{\egroup}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

\setbeamercovered{transparent}

\begin{thebibliography}{1}

% Normal article entry
\setbeamertemplate{bibliography item}[article]
\bibitem{}
\scriptsize Doe, J. (1975).
\newblock\scriptsize Title of the first paper.
\newblock {\em Journal.}

% Transparent article entry on overlay 2
\begin{transpenv}<2>
\setbeamertemplate{bibliography item}[article]
\bibitem{}
\scriptsize Doe, J. (1980).
\newblock\scriptsize Title of the second paper.
\newblock {\em Journal.}
\end{transpenv}

% % BOOK % %        

% Normal book entry

\setbeamertemplate{bibliography item}[book]
\bibitem{}
\scriptsize Doe, J. (2000).
\newblock\scriptsize {\em Title of the first book.}
\newblock Editorial.

% This changes the transparency of the text
\begin{transpenv}<2>
\setbeamertemplate{bibliography item}[book]
\bibitem{}
\scriptsize Doe, J. (2010).
\newblock\scriptsize {\em Title of the second book.}
\newblock Editorial.
\end{transpenv}

% % ONLINE % %

% Normal web entry
\setbeamertemplate{bibliography item}[online]
\bibitem{}
\scriptsize Doe, J. (2001).
\newblock\scriptsize {\em Title of the first website.}
\newblock The website.

% This changes the transparency of the text
\begin{transpenv}<2>
\setbeamertemplate{bibliography item}[online]
\bibitem{}
\scriptsize Doe, J. (2014).
\newblock\scriptsize {\em Title of the second website.}
\newblock The website.
\end{transpenv} 

\end{thebibliography}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

### Method 2

After some research on the `beamer`'s source I found a satisfying solution, since the transparent icons for the bibliography are indeed available [here](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/base/art). For example, the transparent `beamericonarticle.pdf` is `beamericonarticle.20.pdf`.

So the idea is to use `\uncover` for the transparency of the text and select the appropiate icon on each overlay. This is a little tricky if you want to be coherent with `beamer`'s original display and alignment of bibliography icons, so you need to mimick exactly what it does. This is the reason of the new commands `\iconarticle`, `\iconbook`, `\icononline` and their transparent versions `\iconarticletransparent`, `\iconbooktransparent`, `\icononlinetransparent`.

The output:

[image: Output Method 2]

The code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

% Commands to center properly the figures (codes constructed from the information in beamerinnerthemedefault.sty and beamerbaseauxtemplates.sty)
\newcommand{\iconarticle}{\lower3.5pt\hbox{\hskip2pt\includegraphics[width=11pt,height=14pt]{{beamericonarticle}.pdf}}}
\newcommand{\iconarticletransparent}{\lower3.5pt\hbox{\hskip2pt\includegraphics[width=11pt,height=14pt]{{beamericonarticle.20}.pdf}}}
\newcommand{\iconbook}{\lower2pt\hbox{\includegraphics[width=14pt,height=12pt]{{beamericonbook}.pdf}}}
\newcommand{\iconbooktransparent}{\lower2pt\hbox{\includegraphics[width=14pt,height=12pt]{{beamericonbook.20}.pdf}}}
\newcommand{\icononline}{\lower2pt\hbox{\includegraphics[width=14pt,height=14pt]{{beamericononline}.pdf}}}
\newcommand{\icononlinetransparent}{\lower2pt\hbox{\includegraphics[width=14pt,height=14pt]{{beamericononline.20}.pdf}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

\setbeamercovered{transparent}

\begin{thebibliography}{1}

% % ARTICLE % %

% Normal article entry
\setbeamertemplate{bibliography item}[article]
\bibitem{}
\scriptsize Doe, J. (1975).
\newblock\scriptsize Title of the first paper.
\newblock {\em Journal.}

% This chooses the icon (transparent or not)
\only<1>{\setbeamertemplate{bibliography item}{\iconarticle}}
\only<2>{\setbeamertemplate{bibliography item}{\iconarticletransparent}}

% This changes the transparency of the text
\uncover<1>{
\bibitem{}
\scriptsize Doe, J. (1980).
\newblock\scriptsize Title of the second paper.
\newblock {\em Journal.}
}

% % BOOK % %        

% Normal book entry
\setbeamertemplate{bibliography item}[book]
\bibitem{}
\scriptsize Doe, J. (2000).
\newblock\scriptsize {\em Title of the first book.}
\newblock Editorial.

% This chooses the icon (transparent or not)
\only<1>{\setbeamertemplate{bibliography item}{\iconbook}}
\only<2>{\setbeamertemplate{bibliography item}{\iconbooktransparent}}

% This changes the transparency of the text
\uncover<1>{
\bibitem{}
\scriptsize Doe, J. (2010).
\newblock\scriptsize {\em Title of the second book.}
\newblock Editorial.
}

% % ONLINE % %

% Normal web entry
\setbeamertemplate{bibliography item}[online]
\bibitem{}
\scriptsize Doe, J. (2001).
\newblock\scriptsize {\em Title of the first website.}
\newblock The website.

% This chooses the icon (transparent or not)
\only<1>{\setbeamertemplate{bibliography item}{\icononline}}
\only<2>{\setbeamertemplate{bibliography item}{\icononlinetransparent}}

% This changes the transparency of the text
\uncover<1>{
    \bibitem{}
    \scriptsize Doe, J. (2014).
    \newblock\scriptsize {\em Title of the second website.}
    \newblock The website.
}

\end{thebibliography}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Nice. Seems like a good workaround +1

Answer (score 3):

[There is a related question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/37490/how-to-pause-figures-in-beamer). I think Jealie's answer seems to be what you want, but I can't get it to work.

The general problem is the way the transparency is generated. Using custom (text) symbols could be an option (since there is no problem with text) or a tikz picture. That led me to spend way too much time on recreating the article icon (even though a more minimalistic icon would probably be better) in tikz and came up with this work around:

[image]

Generated by:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

\setbeamercovered{transparent}

\setbeamertemplate{bibliography item}{
\begin{tikzpicture}[color=gray,scale=0.4,very thin]
\draw (0.1,0.82)--(.5,.82); %headline
\draw (0.15,0.72)--(.55,.72); %abstact
\draw (0.15,0.62)--(.55,.62);

\draw (0.08,0.48)--(.32,.48); %left column
\draw (0.08,0.38)--(.32,.38);
\draw (0.08,0.28)--(.32,.28);
\draw (0.08,0.18)--(.32,.18);
\draw (0.08,0.1)--(.32,.1);

%right column
\draw[fill=blue!70!black,draw=none] (0.4,0.5)--(.62,.5)--(.62,.4)--(0.4,0.4) --(0.4,0.5);
\draw[fill=red!70!black,draw=none] (0.4,0.4)--(.62,.4)--(.62,.3)--(0.4,0.3) --(0.4,0.4);
\draw[fill=green!70!black,draw=none] (0.4,0.3)--(.62,.3)--(.62,.2)--(0.4,0.2) --(0.4,0.3);
\draw (0.4,0.1)--(.62,.1);

%page
\draw[black,fill=yellow!40!gray,fill opacity=0.3,line width=0.4pt] (0,0) -- (0,.95) -- (0.5,.95) -- (.7,0.75) -- (.7,0) --(0,0);
\draw[black,fill=black!10!brown,join=round] (0.5,.95) -- (0.7,0.75) -- (0.5,0.75) --(0.5,.95);
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\begin{thebibliography}{1}

\uncover<1>{
    \bibitem{}
    \scriptsize Doe, J. (1975).
    \newblock\scriptsize Title of the first paper.
    \newblock {\em Journal.}
}
\uncover<1-2>{
    \bibitem{}
    \scriptsize Doe, J. (1980).
    \newblock\scriptsize Title of the second paper.
    \newblock {\em Journal.}
}

\end{thebibliography}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Good answer and great work recreating the article's icon in `tikz` (+1). However, I found that there are some differences between the `tikz` icon and the original one, so I am still looking for a solution that works with the original icon.