# Transparency/Opacity of figure in a block with uncover in Beamer

Tags: beamer, overlays, transparency, block

I am creating a presentation with Beamer, using Berkeley as theme. On one frame I have the columns environment in order to put two blocks side by side. Each block has a header and contains a picture.

I would like to show both blocks on the first slide and then highlight only the first block on the second slide. I achieved this using the `\uncover` command but, nevertheless, the picture in the second block is still “fully” visible. On the contrary, I would like also the picture to be faded (note: *NOT transparent*).

In other words, this is what I get: [image]
While this is what I would like to get:[image]

This is the MWE I am using:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{beamer}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\mode<presentation>
{
\usetheme{Berkeley}
\setbeamercovered{transparent}
}

%Title
\title[Example]{Example}

%*DOCUMENT*
\begin{document}

%*INTRODUCTION*
\section{Introduction}

%Trees
\subsection[Trees]{Trees}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Introduction:\\ Trees}
\begin{columns}[t]
 \begin{column}{0.48\textwidth}
 \uncover<1,2>{
  \begin{block}{Tree1}
   \begin{figure}
    \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{Tree.jpeg}
        \label{fig:a}
   \end{figure}
  \end{block}}      
 \end{column}
 \begin{column}{0.48\textwidth}
 \uncover<1>{
  \begin{block}{Tree2}
   \begin{figure}
    \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{Tree.jpeg}
        \label{fig:b}
   \end{figure}
  \end{block}}
 \end{column}
\end{columns}
\end{frame} 

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I am just building on top of @samcarter [great answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/354033/95423) and making a new command `\uncovergraphics` for it, for simple reuse (personally I place it in my custom beamer theme):

```
\newcommand<>{\uncovergraphics}[2][{}]{
    % Taken from: <https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/354033/95423>
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] (B) at (4,0)
        {\includegraphics[#1]{#2}};
    \alt#3{}{%
        \fill [draw=none, fill=background, fill opacity=0.9] (B.north west) -- (B.north east) -- (B.south east) -- (B.south west) -- (B.north west) -- cycle;
    }
    \end{tikzpicture}
}
```

Note: I used the color named `background`, which is defined in my colortheme, but change it to your needs.

Then I simply use it like I would for `\includegraphics`:

```
\uncovergraphics<2->[width=\linewidth]{tree1}
```

**EDIT:**

There was [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/136173/95423) already that proposed the same idea, but redefines includegraphics so that it works in any case (e.g after pause command).

Comment: This should be the correct answer, bravo!!!

Answer (score 6):

**Solution 1:**

Produce a second, faded version of the image with some external tool of your choice.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{beamer}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\mode<presentation>
{
\usetheme{Berkeley}
\setbeamercovered{transparent}
}

%Title
\title[Example]{Example}

%*DOCUMENT*
\begin{document}

%*INTRODUCTION*
\section{Introduction}

%Trees
\subsection[Trees]{Trees}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Introduction:\\ Trees}
\begin{columns}[t]
 \begin{column}{0.48\textwidth}
 \uncover<1,2>{
  \begin{block}{Tree1}
   \begin{figure}
    \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{tree1}
        \label{fig:a}
   \end{figure}
  \end{block}}      
 \end{column}
 \begin{column}{0.48\textwidth}
 \uncover<1>{
  \begin{block}{Tree2}
   \begin{figure}
    \centering
        \includegraphics<2>[width=\linewidth]{tree2}
        \includegraphics<1>[width=\linewidth]{tree1}
        \label{fig:b}
   \end{figure}
  \end{block}}
 \end{column}
\end{columns}
\end{frame} 

\end{document}
```

[image]

**Solution 2:**

using `tikz`

```
\documentclass[11pt]{beamer}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\mode<presentation>
{
\usetheme{Berkeley}
\setbeamercovered{transparent}
}

%Title
\title[Example]{Example}
\usepackage{tikz}

%*DOCUMENT*
\begin{document}

%*INTRODUCTION*
\section{Introduction}

%Trees
\subsection[Trees]{Trees}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Introduction:\\ Trees}
\begin{columns}[t]
 \begin{column}{0.48\textwidth}
 \uncover<1,2>{
  \begin{block}{Tree1}
   \begin{figure}
    \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{tree1}
        \label{fig:a}
   \end{figure}
  \end{block}}      
 \end{column}
 \begin{column}{0.48\textwidth}
 \uncover<1>{
  \begin{block}{Tree2}
  \begin{figure}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] (B) at (4,0) {\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{tree1}};
    \only<2>{%
        \fill [draw=none, fill=white, fill opacity=0.7] (B.north west) -- (B.north east) -- (B.south east) -- (B.south west) -- (B.north west) -- cycle;
    }
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{figure}
  \end{block}}
 \end{column}
\end{columns}
\end{frame} 

\end{document}
```

[image]